# Primefaces Autocomplete removes values after page reload

Tags: spring, jsf, couchbase

i am facing a quite strange issue. In fact i am using primfaces (6.0) autocomplete with multiple values.
Everything works as expected except one little nasty issue. As soon as a i saved my data and reload the page (leaving the scope), it looks like all is good, but the values in my multiselect disapear as soon as select a new one.
For example the list looks like that after reloading the page:

*Value1 Value2 Value3*

As soon as a now enter the box and select *Value4* the list looks like that:

*Value4*

All other values disappear even though they are initially there.

Here some code (XHTML)

```
<p:autoComplete multiple="true" value="#{pricelistItemBean.newPricelistItem.subItems}" completeMethod="#{pricelistItemBean.completeItems}"
            var="pl" itemLabel="#{pl.name}" itemValue="#{pl}"
            converter="#{couchbaseEntityConverter}" forceSelection="true" cache="true" >
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{pl.name}"/>
</p:column>
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{pl.description}"/>
</p:column>
```

This is the converter:

```
@Named
@Scope("session")
public class CouchbaseEntityConverter implements Converter {

public static final int SIMPLE_CACHE_SIZE = 20;
private Map<String, CBMain> entities = new HashMap<>(SIMPLE_CACHE_SIZE);
@Autowired
CouchbaseRepository couchbaseRepository;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value != null && value.length() > 0) {
        if (entities.containsKey(value)) {
            return entities.get(value);
        } else {
            CBMain entity = couchbaseRepository.findById(value, CBMain.class);
            if (entities.size() >= SIMPLE_CACHE_SIZE) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(entities.keySet());
                entities.remove(list.get(list.size() - 1));
            }
            entities.put(value, entity);
            return entity;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value != null && value instanceof CBMain) {
        return ((CBMain) value).getId();
    }
    return null;
}

public Map<String, CBMain> getEntities() {
    return entities;
}
```

}

The Entity is basically just loaded like
`@PostConstruct`

Things i did:

- I copied the list (autocomplete values) at the `@PostConstruct` method just to check. They list is definitely set and correct.
- i checked the itemSelect / itemUnselect Events. Here it might be worth to mention, that as soon as the itemUnselect-Event is triggered, the list is set back to an empty list already
- if i add / remove just the items after the pagereload, it all works as expected.

I am using Spring/Tomcat 8/JSF2.2/Couchbase and i am kind of running out of ideas.. any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, thanks for everybody who checked that question.
The solution is (of course) very simple.

In fact, couchbase (spring-couchbase) does not store the ID (if annotated as @Id) in the json-object. (its saved as META(bucket).id)

That again means, that my list of objects basically looked like that:

```
 {
    prop1:"val1",
    prop2:"val2",
    subItems: {
       prop1:"val1",
       prop2:"val2"
    }
 }
```

This JSON  transformed into a POJO made my converter pretty useless, since i expected the json to look like that:

```
    subItems: {
       id: "myId...",
       prop1:"val1",
       prop2:"val2"
    }
```

so, having an ID. Which was just not that case and that caused

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
if (value != null && value instanceof CBMain) {
    return ((CBMain) value).getId();
}
return null;
```

}

to always return null ....

Comment: so all tags (spring, jsf, tomcat, primefaces and autocomplete) are in fact unrelated, but the tag should have been 'couchbase'? ;-)

Comment: Well... Yeah :). I was sure at the beginning that it has nothing todo with the data ... how wrong you can be sometimes... :-/